# What does the below C code does - is it redundant

Tags: c

We have a production Socket code and often I find below code in it:

```
struct sockaddr_in* sin = (struct sockaddr_in*)to;
(void)sin;
```

The variable sin is nowherfe further used? Since it is production code I am not sure if these statements has any importance at all? What is the code trying ti achieve here - from my side it is completly redudant code

Comment: Most likely `sin` was used, later all references to `sin` were removed, the line `(void)sin` added just to silence the warning

Comment: @qrdl: It would be easier then to just remove the previous line as well, if `sin` isn't referenced. I am (wildly, and hence comment only) guessing someone had the first line in there for easier breakpoint debugging (making debugger aware of "real" type of `to`), and forgot to `#ifndef NDEBUG` or completely remove the artifact once the debugging was done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a benign effect.

It's primarily used to suppress compiler warnings about unused variables, `sin` in this case. If `sin` indeed is not used outside these two lines, then they can be safely removed.

(I ban its use as it can lead to undefined behaviour and catastrophic optimisation on that branch if `sin` is not initialised.)

Comment: If in case the variable is not used further and code compiles then we can delete the two lines

Comment: @Programmer: yes, you can.

Comment: UB? Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Vorac: E.g. `int *p; (void)p;` is UB

Comment: @bathsheba.  Cite Please.

Comment: @EvilTeach: It's not authoritative, but see https://riptutorial.com/c/example/1472/use-of-an-uninitialized-variable.

Answer (score 0):

This is used to avoid compiler and static analysis tool warnings for unused variables

Comment: If in case the variable is not used further and code compiles then we can delete the two lines